# Visual Studio 2019 : Where Can I remove the Nuget credentials already added in visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, nuget

I added the Nuget source in visual studio and provided the credentials, now I want to login with a different username  and password , how can I remove the credentials already added to the Visual Studio 2019. Are there any options in visual studio?

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for definitely-not-code pieces of text. Have you tried just removing the source entirely and readding it?

Comment: Did you check credentials in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager?